# Purpose of /etc/centos-release-upstream

Tags: centos, filesystems

What does the `centos-release-upstream` file mean in CentOS? The `centos-release` file already tells me that a CentOS 7.2.x release was installed.

```
root# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 



root# cat /etc/centos-release-upstream 
Derived from Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.2 (Source)



root# cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must be aware that

> CentOS (/sɛnt.ɑːs/, from Community Enterprise Operating System) is a Linux distribution that attempts to provide a free, enterprise-class, community-supported computing platform which aims to be functionally compatible with its upstream source, Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL).[5][6] In January 2014

from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS)

so this centos-release-upstream file is declaring that it is compatible with/Derived from Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.2 (Source).
So you will be able to use rpm which are compatible with RHEL 7.2.
CentOS version and compatible RHEL version is same in this case but not necessarily same each time.
Know that CentOS is community edition which is intended to give feel/working simmilar that of RHEL 
So these two files show different information and not the same.

Answer (score 1):

It tells you that the version of CentOS you're running is [based on RHEL 7.2](https://wiki.centos.org/Download#head-d549a49224205bd03d35e714327a5287fb08e95d-2). Obviously you can figure that out currently from the CentOS version, but having it explicitly in a different file means that you can find that information without hard-coding the knowledge that CentOS versions match RHEL versions — if that ever changes in the future, `/etc/centos-release-upstream` will still contain the correct information.